# Combination await with ContinueWith

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I met the following asynchronous code (simplified for this example) which I'm trying to understand:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new Foo();

        try
        {
            var bar = new Bar();
            await foo.ComputeNumber(bar.GetNumberAsync());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Logged exception: {e}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"The number is {foo.Number}");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Number { get; private set; } = 0;

    public async Task ComputeNumber(Task<int> inputTask)
    {
        await inputTask.ContinueWith(x => Number = x.Result);
    }
}

public class Bar
{
    public async Task<int> GetNumberAsync()
    {
        return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            if (DateTime.Now.Date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday)
            {
                throw new Exception("This function works only on Mondays.");
            }
            return 17;
        });
    }
}
```

This code works as I expected (at least I hope so), but I think this problem should be solved in one of the following ways (I think both are correct). The `Bar` class will remain unchanged.

***First (async/await) method:***

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new Foo();

        try
        {
            var bar = new Bar();
            await foo.ComputeNumber(bar.GetNumberAsync());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Logged exception: {e}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"The number is {foo.Number}");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Number { get; private set; } = 0;

    public async Task ComputeNumber(Task<int> inputTask)
    {
        Number = await inputTask;
    }
}
```

***Second (task-based) method:***

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new Foo();
        var bar = new Bar();
        foo.ComputeNumber(bar.GetNumberAsync());

        Console.WriteLine($"The number is {foo.Number}");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Number { get; private set; } = 0;

    public void ComputeNumber(Task<int> inputTask)
    {
        inputTask.ContinueWith(x =>
        {
            if (x.IsFaulted)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Logged exception: {x.Exception}");
            }
            else
            {
                Number = x.Result;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I appreciate every explanation of why the original example of using asynchronous code could have been written this way.

Comment: Your `First (async/await) method` looks correct, just set the number with `await`, there's no need for the callback-esque `ContinueWith`. As for why it was done like that in the first place I'm not sure there's a way to know without talking to the original dev.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of `await` as a language feature that replaces most uses of `ContinueWith`, and so to mix the two seems unnecessary.

Note that your second rewrite is not the same as the first, in two ways.

1. It swallows errors instead of surfacing them.
2. It doesn't return a `Task` so the caller will not know when the `Number` has been set to the final result.

`ComputeNumber` is of dubious purpose (this may be as a result of it being simplified for posting here). Why not simply `await bar.GetNumberAsync()` and then use the obtained value in subsequent statements? The point of `await` is to allow `Task<T>` to be treated much the same as `T` in procedural code.